# Create multiple tiles that fade into different images using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a web project and I want to make a 3x2 row of tiles that when you mouse over them the tile will fade out and fade in with a new one containing the image.

I have multiple tiles that are images using the DIV class `.previewBox`. When you mouse over these images I use JQuery to fade out the image and fade back in with a new one (using a JQuery plugin called waitForImages which is specifically tailored for loading images in JavaScript) The problem is I want each tile to fade with a different set of images. I thought of putting all of the first set of images (The preview images) in an array and the second set of images (The flip images) in a different array and when you mouse over and it would want to set the flip image it would call flipArray.indexOf(this) but since the JavaScript is detecting the div I am not sure if that will work because "this" isn't referring to the image in the array.

I am still really learning javascript and I am not really sure how to detect which image you are hovering over and take its index number to switch it out with another picture.

I have the script for fading images but right now I have the image location hard coded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Document is ready to load
    var hov = false;
    //Since there is more then one tile using the .previewBox I use the .each command
    $('.previewBox').each(function() {
        var previewBox = $(this); // Won't create as many objects this way.
        previewBox.mouseenter(function() // On mouse enter
        {
            if (hov === false) //Keeps animation from repeating
            {
                hov = true; // Sets boolean for mouse leave
                previewBox.fadeOut(function() //Fades out
                {
                    previewBox.waitForImages(function() //Loads images
                    {
                        previewBox.stop().fadeIn(); //Fades in
                    });
                    previewBox.attr("src", "Images/Portfolio/Art_Bike_Flip.png"); //New image location. 
                });
            };
        });
    });
    $('.previewBox').each(function() {
        var previewBox = $(this);
        previewBox.mouseleave(function() {
            if (hov === true) {
                hov = false;
                previewBox.fadeOut(function() {
                    previewBox.waitForImages(function() {
                        previewBox.stop().fadeIn();
                    });
                    previewBox.attr("src", "Images/Portfolio/Art_Bike_Preview.png");
                });
            };
        });
    });
});
```